# Shuffle each line in a file a certain amount (control degree of randomness) using Python

Tags: python, random, shuffle

I have a file (test.txt) which contains a number on each row.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
etc.
```

I want to be able to shuffle each line around the file but only within certain boundaries i.e. shuffle each line ±1 or shuffle each line ±5. Essentially I want to be able to control the degree of shuffling with the end goal being several different outputs, some of which only deviate from the original file slightly (each line is in approximately the same position) while others differentiate by a large amount (each line is far away from its original position) and everything in between.

E.g.

```
2
1
3
5
4
6
etc.
```

At one end and:

```
6
3
1
5
2
4
etc.
```

at the other.

I have seen plenty of questions asking about straight up random shuffling every line but I haven't been able to find anything about being able to control the degree of "randomness".

Comment: please add your attempt to solve the problem (simple working code example)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?  Its difficult to test without something to run it on:

```
# read the linesinfile list, but store a mini list with the original positions of lines (index) and original line (value)
x = [[index, value] for index, value in enumerate(linesinfile)]
# use the random library
import random
# make a new list from x, but subtract or add a random number between -5 and +5 to the index values (this will be used to reorder the lines in file)
y = [[i[0] +  random.randrange(-5, 5, 1), i[1]] for i in x]
# sort the list, y, by the new index values
# as the index is an integer, there could be clashes (duplicates in index value)
# either fix those by converting to float or use a float random number to start with, or just let the list sort as python defaults to
y.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
#print the original lines in the new order. 
for k in y:
    print(k[1])
```

Comment: Edited a few examples in. Can you explain which parts of the code control the various parameters?

Comment: how do you guarantee that random numbers are unique?